How to assign ALL file types to a custom action for file-manager (MIME-type comprising ALL files?)
I am using PCManFM file-manager and custom actions to apply my own scripts to selected files and folders. In the .desktop files where the custom actions are defined the desired MIME-types must be given. When right-clicking on a file with a corresponding MIME-type, the script will show up in the menu. Now I run into this problem: there seems to be no MIME-type for ALL file types (as if writing * in a script), so I can't assign a script to any kind of file. As a workaround I am using scripts on a whole folder instead. But I wonder whether there is a better solution.
BTW: There is only a custom-actions tag for thunar file manager, so I selected it even though I am using PCManFM.
